# Requesting to join an organization in CKAN

Tags: ckan

I have not been able to find any information regarding how a user can request to join an organization in CKAN. Does anyone have experience with this?

It seems logical that the organization page would display some information about the organization admin, but this is not the case, for my site at least.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

All the documentation I can find (as of version 2.3) is that users can only be invited to join an organization:
http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/authorization.html

It is possible to customize the organization home page template to show the admin's email address or to include a button that would "request access" via an automated email to the admin, for example, but this would require some crafty CKAN template work or possibly even the creation of a custom CKAN extension.

Comment: Do you know if this has been improved since then? I would like to have a "request access" button. Or do I need to implement this myself?